# Get the filename of drag&drop data from explorer to Windows Forms

Tags: .net, windows, c++-cli

I'm struggling with a task I assumed was going to be simple.

I have a Windows Forms application, written in C++/CLI. I want the user to be able to drag and drop a file into the form for some kind of processing.

I've set the forms behavior to **AllowDrop** and the **DragEnter** event raises.

How I can retrieve the filename? I saw [this example in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9017/A-Simple-Drag-And-Drop-How-To-Example) but haven't got any luck porting to C++/CLI

This is what I tried:

```
private: System::Void tabSingle_DragEnter(System::Object^  sender, 

System::Windows::Forms::DragEventArgs^  e)
{
   if ( e->Effect == DragDropEffects::Link)
   {
      // This is true
   }

   try
   {
      String^ filename = (String^) e->Data->GetData("FileName");

   }
   catch(...)
   {
      // System.InvalidCastException: Impossible to convert an object of type 'System.String[]' in to'System.String'
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I updated the answer with the description of the exception I received. Looks like the object expected is a System.String[]. How should I modify that line to have the same behavior as this line on C# (from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9017/A-Simple-Drag-And-Drop-How-To-Example))

`Array data=((IDataObject)e.Data).GetData("FileName") as Array;`

Comment: "these always fails": *How* does it fail? What is the exception that you're getting?

Comment: Updated my question with the exception received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array syntax in C++/CLI is `array<String^>^ filenames = ...`.

Since the exception is telling you that you have a string array, cast directly to that type, rather than the generic type `Array`, like they did in the C# example. (Naturally, check that it is a string array before using it, etc.)

Comment: Thanks.. I got it working now. Just to complement... how do I check it's a string array prior to assigning? GetData() documentation says it returns a System::Object

Comment: Do a `dynamic_cast` and check for null before continuing. That's the equivalent to `as` and a null check in C#. (There is no direct equivalent to C#'s `is`.) I misspoke in my answer; now corrected.